# database setting when deployed war file

Tags: jsp

i have done a project in jsp.i have make war of  the entire project.when i deploy this war to another machine it gives error that login failed,cz my database(sql server 2005) username and password(which is now hard coded use in jsp file) is different than that another machine.
i want some trick that my project can run on any machine without creating connectivity problem.
cz i want to make such kind of software Of my project,which will be distributed to many machines .so in that case this connectivity problem should not occure
Pl z help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure database related credentials in an xml file rather than hard codding  and then while deployment you can change in xml file.Other trick is that you can use property file and the same thing can be done.

Other way you can define data source and then you can use data-source lookup and can get the connection.

So finally it depends what is your requirement and then based on that  you can provide solutions.

Comment: ya but whenever i will give this software to another,everytime i have to change that xml or property file,i dont want to do that

Comment: Could you provide some documentation concerning datasource?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not hardcode the username and password (or indeed any configuration details like these) into the jsp file.

You need to externalize the connection details, prefereably outside of the war file so you can deploy the same war to different environments)

You should place the connection details in a property file and read from that. You can then either configure your build process to build a different war for each environment - or build one war and unpack this for every deployment and overwrite the connection properties then repack the war. There are other  options depending on you web server.

What environment are you running this in - Tomcat? Jboss?

Comment: How do you build the war file?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't store hardcoded credentials in your web app.

So you must store them outside, on the server on which you deploy.

Outside of specific container features like datasources, you may :

1) use java Preferences, but there are so many bugs with them, especially if using tomcat on linux, that I wouldn't consider them (I did, I cleaned)

2) Put the connection properties in external files. Here's how I do it :

I have in my WEB-INF directory a text file listing all authorized locations for those proprerties. This file is deployed as is on all servers. Here's an example :

```
# This file lists all the locations where mysoft will look for
# an XML config file when starting.
# It's recommended to use links to simplify parameterization but
# it's also possible to enrich this file.

 # standard windows locations
 c:\mycomp\mysoft\config\config.xml
 d:\mycomp\mysoft\config\config.xml

 # standard linux location
 /var/lib/mycomp/mysoft/config/config.xml
```

And my webapp simply chooses the first found file when initializing.
  To do this I implemented a ServletContextListener in which I read the text file and store the config.

Here's a very simplified version of my listener :

```
public class MySoftServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

public final static String CONFIG_LIST_PATH = "/WEB-INF/config-paths.txt";

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
    InputStream list = context.getResourceAsStream(WORLD_LIST_PATH);
    try {
        BufferedReader listReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(list));
        String line;
        while ((line=listReader.readLine())!=null) {
            if (line.length()<4 || line.charAt(0)=='#') continue;
            File file = new File(line);
            if (file.exists()) {

                // log config from the file and, for example, store it in a singleton

                break;
            } else {
                log.info("No config in file " + line + " (file doesn't exist)");
            }
        }
        list.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.severe("Error while looking for a config : " + e.toString());
    }
}

}
```

The servlet context listener is referenced in my web.xml like this :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mycomp.mysoft.webapp.MySoftServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: i didnt get it,can u plz explain simply by stepwise

Comment: Could you provide some documentation about datasource?

Answer (score -1):

Not just credentials. You should not hardcode any database properties. JavaEE provides wonderful ways to configure the datasource at runtime:

- If you are using Servlet 3.0 Container, you can configure the datasource properties in web.xml and use the datasource
- You can lookup datasource resource with a given name in the application and bind your required datasource . You can also let Servlet Container inject the datasource if you define a resource annotation.

Comment: Hi Ramesh! What kind of datasorce do you meen? Is it a class, is it some propery or..? Could you provide some documentation?